# Bookmarklet for iOS Rewrite URL and visit in Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, bookmarklet

I'm trying to automate a process I do manually. I visit webpages at the following url with different UserNo. I then have to individually copy and paste the UserNo into a new web address to search for it.

Example 1 of source URL

http://www. testdomain.com/ViewProfile.asp?UserNo=2978359&Keywords&Test=qw12&Var=Qatar

I would like to be able to click on a Bookmarklet bookmark that takes me from the above website to;

http://www .differentdomain.com/q=2978359

Example 2 of source URL

http://www .testdomain.com/ViewProfile.asp?UserNo=1123478&Keywords&Test=qw12&Var=Denmark

I want the Bookmarklet when clicked to take me to http://www .differentdomain.com/q=1123478

The UserNo is only numbers.

Thanks in advance

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the problem

javascript:var%20q=document.location.href.match(/UserID=(.*?)(?=&|$)/i);{q=q[1];window.open('http://www.differentdomain.com/search?q='+q);}

Or

javascript:(function(){var%20q=document.location.href.match(/UserID=(.*?)(?=&|$)/i);q=q[1];window.open('http://google.com/search?q='+q);})();

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

And the call to get the parameter like

```
var UserNo = gup( 'UserNo' );
```

And then

```
window.location.replace("http://www.differentdoman.com/q="+UserNo);
```

Hope it helps

You can find more help [here](http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html)

Comment: Hi Braian, thank you for this. It makes perfect sense. Not being too technically minded, how could I convert this into a working Bookmarklet for Safari on iOS? thank you in advance for your advice

Comment: For example a Bookmarklet for camelcamelcamel for Amazon uk is like this javascript:location.href='http://uk.camelcamelcamel.com/search?q='+window.location.href;

Comment: you need it in one line without the function?

Comment: can you use something like this?
javascript:location.href='uk.camelcamelcamel.com/search?q='+‌​gup( 'UserNo' );

Comment: Yes. Needed as one line to use in iOS Safari browser. I need to visit the page with the UserNo and then when I click on Bookmarklet it extracts the UserNo and transfers me to the new page with the UserNo. Thanks so far for your help :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help